# Google OAuth2 get access token Missing grant_type

Tags: c#, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-oauth

I am using the following code to get the access token for google OAuth2.
At some point it has been working fine, but I've done something/something's happened and I can't work out what and now I am getting :

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

When I try the post with the params in postman I get

> {
>     "error": "invalid_request",
>     "error_description": "Required parameter is missing: grant_type"
>   }

```
 using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {

            byte[] response =
                client.UploadValues("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token","POST", new NameValueCollection()
                    {
                        {"code",HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(authCode.ToString())},
                        {"redirect_uri", Uri.EscapeDataString("http://YouTubeTest.org/testpage.aspx")},
                        {"client_id", HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(clientId)},
                        {"client_secret", HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(clientSecret)},
                        {"grant_type", "authorization_code"}
                    });

            string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
            XElement node = XElement.Parse(JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(result, "Root").ToString());
            string refreshToken = node.Element("refresh_token").Value;
            string accessToken = node.Element("access_token").Value;

        //more work to do something with tokens
        }
```

This was previously working without the URL encoding, I added this in to test after looking through a few posts with similar problems but can't seem to find an answer that will make it work.

Comment: I think you need to set the header Content-Type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: Having just tested thus in postman, and using the body tab and x-www-form-urlencoded it also seems that the redirect uri is also case sensitive! I have it working in postman now.

Comment: @Frode and Bex please work together into creating an actuall answer and marking it as Correct. Not only you'll get points at StackOverflow, it also makes the possible answer more visible. now, at first glance, it seemed like there wasn't any answer while you 2 actually solved my problems;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the http POST-request header's `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`